# How to prove $\prod_{n=1} ^{22} \frac{\tan(2n-1)}{\tan(2n)} \lt \sqrt{\tan(1)}$

Tags: inequality

How to prove $$P = \prod_{n=1} ^{22} \frac{\tan(2n-1)}{\tan(2n)} \lt \sqrt{\tan(1)}$$
I reached the following $$P^2 = \tan(1) \prod_{n=1} ^{22}  \frac{\tan(2n-1) \tan(2n+1)}{{\tan(2n)}^2}$$
But don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong!
$$\prod_{k=1}^{22}\frac{\tan(2k-1)}{\tan2k}=7377.3...>\sqrt{\tan1}.$$
See here:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prod_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E22(tan(2k-1)%2Ftan(2k))